# How to make a common UIViewController in storyboard iOS?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, storyboard

For example, I have a Question UIViewController. I can set up this question interface (add other views); after that, I want to click a button in the current interface to bring me to another Question interface.

Is there a workaround for this in storyboard? I can manage to achieve it by using xib files (NavigationController push). I hope I have made myself clear in this question.

It's like a common `UIViewController`, is there such concept with storyboards?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use segues, a basic technique of storyboards.

See e.g. [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/StoryboardSegue.html) help file / video.